# How to make dynamic updates to the database using a list in python

Tags: python, sql-server

```
if year in Year:
  #print 'executing'
  for rows in range(1,sheet.nrows):
      records = []
      FIP = str(sheet.cell(rows, 1).value)
      for cols in range(9,sheet.ncols):
          records.append(str(sheet.cell(rows,cols).value))
      cur.execute("UPDATE " + str(table_name) + " SET " + (str(variables[0]) + "= \'{0}\', ".format(records[0])
                  + str(variables[1]) + " = \'{0}\', ".format(records[1])
                  + str(variables[2]) + " = \'{0}\', ".format(records[2])
                  + str(variables[3]) + " = \'{0}\', ".format(records[3])
                  + str(variables[4]) + " = \'{0}\',".format(records[4])
                  + str(variables[5]) + " = \'{0}\', ".format(records[5])
                  + str(variables[6]) + " = \'{0}\' ".format(records[6])+
                                        "WHERE DATA_Year='2010'AND FIPS='{0}'".format(FIP)))
```

The above code is updating 7 columns whose names are stored in the list 'variables'. 
I want to make it dynamic so that if number of elements(columns) in the list 'variables' is increased, it should update all the columns and not just 7.
I tried doing that using this code:

```
if year in Year:
  #print 'executing'
  for rows in range(1,sheet.nrows):
      records = []
      FIP = str(sheet.cell(rows, 1).value)
      for cols in range(9,sheet.ncols):
          records.append(str(sheet.cell(rows,cols).value))
      for x in range(0,len(variables)):
          #print x
          cur.execute("UPDATE " + str(table_name) + " SET " + (str(variables[x])) + "= \'{0}\', ".format(records[x])
                                        + "WHERE DATA_Year='2010' AND FIPS='{0}'".format(FIP))
```

But I am getting the error:
`pypyodbc.ProgrammingError: (u'42000', u"[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.")`

It would be great if someone can help me figure out what's wrong with my code and whether there is a alternate way of doing what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You will find it easier to use parameter-substitution.  See [params](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle), and note that **execute** takes a sequence argument.  Then that line starts to look something like,

```
cur.execute(sql, records)
```

If memory permits (it probably does), you may find **executemany** performs better: you call it once with an array of records.

With that in mind, the *dynamic* part of your question comes into focus.  Construct the parameterized query string as you iterate over `cols`.  When that's done, you should have a matched set (in effect) of parameter placeholders and elements in `records`.  Then tack on the WHERE clause, append FIP to records, and execute.

HTH.